# How to use MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary inside a vector?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-vectordrawable

I have this vector:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportWidth="100"
    android:viewportHeight="100">
  <path
      android:fillColor="?android:colorPrimary"
      android:pathData="M61.3,27v-0.1l-0.1..."/>
</vector>
```

I tried using  `?android:colorPrimary` or `android:fillColor="?attr/colorPrimary"` but it doesn't work. How can I set MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary color?